# Files are not getting saved in Android Download Folder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

I am using Download Manager to Download PDFs and Images. Downloaded files are not getting saved in Download Folder. Here is my code.

`

```
val fileName = "MG Uploaded Documents"

        val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadUrl))
            .setTitle("Download")
            .setDescription("Downloading")
        request.setDestinationUri(
            Uri.fromFile(File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                    .toString() , fileName)))
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
        val dm = this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        dm.enqueue(request)
        this.T("File is Downloading. Please wait!")
```

`
This code is in Home Activity. Any help.

Comment: Have you try   mRequest.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(mContext, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename); in place of setDestinationUri

Comment: also please make sure that you have added permission in manifest.<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Yes, I have tried your code but still it's not saving files in the Download folder.
I have already given WRITE_STORAGE permission and I am using Android 12.

Comment: Can you share related logs and share more code. filename should be valid format

Comment: Did you ever solve this one? Have the same issue

Comment: Yes. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was not saving the file name with .pdf extension.
Below is the working code.

```
 private fun downloadPDF(url: String) {
    
    val fileName = "YourPdfName.pdf"
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
                .setTitle("PDF Download")
                .setDescription("Downloading")
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
    
            //  val dm = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
            val dm = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
            dm.enqueue(request)
        }
```